# Own TYPO3 extension is executed only on the first page call (headless TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

It's TYPO3 10.4 and headless CMS is being used.

I have a strange behavior with an own extension.

It looks like it is only executed 1 time.

Behaviour:
Page call -> every thing is looking good.
When calling another page our extension is not being called.
After clearing the cache it is possible to render any page. But only the 1st one called executes our extension.

We have different calls inside the extension.
A simple TypoScript

```
page.10.fields.navigationTree =< lib.primaryNavigation
```

is missing.

And other content modules throwing a

> Content Element with uid "X" and type "XXXXX" has no rendering definition!

Any ideas? Maybe caching options?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "own extension"?

From what you said there, I assume that you have plugin that should not be cached? If so, declare it with `USER_INT` instead of `USER` cObj.

Also, error `foo has no rendering definition!` means that there is no tt_content typoscript rendering definition for your element. Please take a look at `heedless` tt_content content elements definitions in typoscript to take a look how you should declare your element.